# escape curly braces { in a string to support String.Format

Tags: c#, .net

I have strings that I read from the database, these strings are fed into String.Format method, if a string has '{' '}' braces but these braces are not escaped correctly for String.Format (i.e add another '{' to escape them) the String.Format will throw an exception.

The string have any combination of these braces, so in essence the method needs to go through the string and figure out if '{' have a closing one and if together they form a valid place holder for String.Format (i.e. {5}), the ones that don't need to be escaped correctly.

I can write a method to do that, but was wondering if there is anything built into .NET, or anything out there that already does this ?

A string example is the following:

***Hello {0}, please refer to our user manual for more information {or contact us at: XXXX}"***

As you can tell feeding this into String.Format will throw an exception on the **{or contact us at: XXXX}**

Comment: A sample input and output would be nice

Comment: Pretty simple regex if you can guarantee never wanting to escape {digit}.

Comment: Where are these strings coming from? Wouldn't it be easier to restrict the input (and disallow {})? Or if the valid place holders come from a different place than the invalid ones, it would be easy to escape the "invalid" part and join the parts together.

Comment: Is it possible to use a different escape character for your custom processing tool? You chose one that is already taken. Other option is to escape when storing and un scape it after the string.Format has taken place... `var s = string.Format("Hello {0} plese {{or contact}}", ... );`

Comment: Do you have control of the code that inserts the strings into the database? If so, you'd be easier off if you store it with the double braces, I think. If that's not an option, what do you want to do with the string `"{{"` (already doubled)? Leave it as is, or turn it into `"{{{{"`? How about more complex format strings such as `{0:d}`?

Comment: @Marc, it isn't that simple, since string formats are so much more than just {0}.  Example: `{0:dd}`
`{0:dd/MM/yyyy}`
`{0:hh:mm:ss}`
`{0:0,.}`
`{0:(#).##}`
`{0:00.0000}`
`{0:0%}`
`{0:00e+0}`
`{0:x4}`
`{0:c}`
`{0,10}`
`{0,-10}`

Comment: Or course, if they will only ever have {0} as the placeholder in a format string, the regex _is_ simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
string input = "Hello {0}, please refer for more information {or contact us at: XXXX}";
   Regex rgx = new Regex("(\\{(?!\\d+})[^}]+})");
string replacement = "{$1}";
string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);

Console.WriteLine("String {0}", result);

// Hello {0}, please refer for more information {{or contact us at: XXXX}}
```

... assuming that the only strings that should not be escaped are of format `{\d+}`.

There are two caveats here. First, we may encounter already-escaped curvy braces - `{{`. Fix for it is more-o-less easy: add more lookarounds...

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("(\\{(?!\\d+})(?!\\{)(?<!\\{\\{)[^}]+})");
```

... in other words, when trying to replace a bracket, make sure it's a lonely one. )

Second, formats themselves may not be so simple - and as the complexity of those that actually may be present in your strings grows, so does the regex's one. For example, this little beasty won't attempt to fix format string that start with numbers, then go all the way up to `}` symbol without any space in between:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("(\\{(?!\\d\\S*})(?!\\{)(?<!\\{\\{)[^}]+})");
```

As a sidenote, even though I'm the one of those people that actually like to have two problems (well, sort of), I do shudder when I look at this.

**UPDATE:** If, as you said, you need to escape each single occurrence of `{` and `}`, your task is actually a bit easier - but you will need two passes here, I suppose:

```
Regex firstPass = new Regex("(\\{(?!\\d+[^} ]*}))");
string firstPassEscape = "{$1";
...
Regex secondPass        = new Regex("((?<!\\{\\d+[^} ]*)})");
string secondPassEscape = "$1}";
```

Comment: +1 - though might be worth including some thinking around the optional ':SOMEFORMAT' part of a format string; e.g; string date = String.Format("{0:dd/mm/yyyy}");

Comment: Updated the answer mentioning both possible failure points; it's showing that it took three or four times to actually make it (again, more-o-less) right.

Comment: this is good, but I need to account for places where a single '{' or '}' may appear.

Comment: @Pacman Updated the answer yet again; now I don't actually think that `{{` shouldn't be transformed into `{{{{`, and that reflected too in that final code snippet. )

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to use a different escape character for your custom processing tool? Because you you chose one that is already taken!.

If it is not possible, then other option is to escape it when storing it. It will be un-escaped automatically when the string.Format ends.

```
var s = string.Format("Hello {0} please ... {{or contact}}", customer.Name );
// Now use s as needed 
// now is: "Hello Joe please ... {or contact}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies, but keep in mind that a string may also have just one '{' not both, or they can appear backward, like so '}' '{'

Comment: I still think you have to protect them upon insertion.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
myString = Regex.Replace(myString, @"\{(\D+)\}", "{{$1}}");
```

Comment: Please supply some detail on why this regex should work. This answer is in the "Log Quality Posts" list.

Comment: This regex will fail if that `{...}` string contains at least one digit.

Comment: If I'm to understand the question, he wants to escape braces that are not part of a format specification...e.g., he wants to escape stuff like {hello} and not stuff like {0} {1} etc